# Understanding functions

Tags: python

So I've been practicing with functions but it just occurred to me now:

When you type in `float(3.14)`, you are simply calling the `float` function that has already been defined by the almighty built in Python. It works similarly to user defined functions like this one:

```
def power (x):
    for i in range(x):
        x2=i**2
        print(x2)

power(4)
```

I mean float is also a data type so its probably not **exactly** the same, but is my logic sound?

Answer (score 2):

[`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) is a type. At the same time, it is callable like a function:

```
>>> type(float)
<class 'type'>
>>> callable(float)
True


>>> def power (x):
...     for i in range(x):
...         x2=i**2
...         print(x2)
...
>>> type(power)
<class 'function'>
>>> callable(power)
True
```

In python, types, classes, objects with `__call__` methods beside functions, methods are callable.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you're calling a float() function, yes.

On a different note:

The power function that you've defined probably doesn't behave like you want it to.

You're shadowing your `x` parameter in the function with your `x` variable in the for loop.

No matter what you input, you're getting the same result because your x is instantly overwritten.

```
def power (x):
    for x in range(6):
        x = x ** 2
        print(x)

>>> power(1)
0
1
4
9
16
25
>>> power(10)
0
1
4
9
16
25
```

Comment: ah, I quickly wrote that up without double checking. Thanks for pointing that out.